# Domain name is coming after directory name in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, dns, analytics

Any idea why I'm getting many wrong landing page where domain name is after a directory name. Below is an example from Google Analytics

```
microsoft/www.tutorialspoint.com
linux/www.tutorialspoint.com
mac/www.tutorialspoint.com
```

Where as correct landing page should have been as below:

```
www.tutorialspoint.com/microsoft
www.tutorialspoint.com/linux
www.tutorialspoint.com/mac
```

Not sure if I'm loosing many visits due to this. Kindly give your expert advice on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you check the admin section in you GA account/View Settings/Filters ? GA does not, by itself, include the domain name in the reports, so you either have a misconfigured filter or your code ist set up to include the domain (and does it in the wrong order).

Comment: Thanks Eike for your response on this. I'm fine as long as I'm not missing hits because these microsoft/www.tutorialspoint.com are not valid...